# Proper way to destroy every session of the same user in Node + Express?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm trying to add a "log out from all devices" button to my Express web app and, to accomplish that, I thought I could create a Redis array for every user to store every session id such user logs in with and, upon clicking the button, iterate through the array and destroy each session individually.
How do you go about coding this? I've tried after reading the docs, but haven't quite succeeded. Also, is there a better way to accomplish my goal?
EDIT (adding code): to explain in detail what I'm currently doing, upon every new login I run the following command: `client.sadd(req.session.key, req.session.id);`, where `req.session.key` is a unique id I assign to each user; the "log out from all devices" button triggers the following function:

```
client.multi().smembers(req.session.key).exec((err, entries) => {
    console.log(entries[0]);
    entries[0].forEach(id => {
        store.destroy(id);
    });
});
```

which doesn't work for several reasons: 1) as it turns out, it doesn't actually log out every instance of the user and 2) the session id's stored in the array stay there forever and I haven't understood how (if there's a way) to automatically delete them after a certain time has passed (for instance the `maxAge` of the cookies)

Comment: "haven't quite succeeded" What have you tried? What went wrong? Show your code.

Comment: I have added code and explanations to the original post

Comment: An auto log out system can be complex. For starters, you need a background worker to clear out all the outdated sessions. You need to work your API to check if a session is still valid and, if not, return a "LOGGED_OUT" error to the client. And if you want the client to be automatically logged out whenever the session is closed from elsewhere, you need some kind of pub-sub system using, for example, sockets or RTC to allow the server to communicate to the client that their session is no longer valid.

Comment: I handle the log out on the client by running a middleware upon entering a new page (or, really, doing any action) which automatically kicks the user to the home page (or, in case of a post request, I return a json containing `{"success":0}`). So, about the outdated sessions, Redis doesn't have a way to automize that?

Comment: You can use the [`EXPIRE`](https://redis.io/commands/expire) command to give Redis entries a timeout value, after which they will be automatically deleted.